# Get List of Last 15 Days Date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, hive, calendar, hiveql

Could SQL get list of date of last 15 days date in a single query?

We can get today date with

> `select current_date()`

We also can get last 15 days date with

> `select date_add(current_date(), -15)`

But how to show the list of last 15 days date?
For example the output is

```
2020-05-17, 
2020-05-18, 
2020-05-19, 
2020-05-20, 
2020-05-21, 
2020-05-22, 
2020-05-23, 
2020-05-24, 
2020-05-25, 
2020-05-26, 
2020-05-27, 
2020-05-28, 
2020-05-29, 
2020-05-30, 
2020-05-31
```

Comment: An RDBMS is for the storage and retrieval of relational data. For other things, consider using application level code.

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina I'm using hive version 1.1.0-cdh5.16.2 rUnknown

Comment: Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and show the output.

Comment: @Akina i've told you above. The version is 1.1.0-cdh5.16.2 rUnknown

Comment: If so then remove errorneous MySQL tag.

Comment: Hive does not support recursive CTE. So generate numbers pseudotable in CTE using static numbers list and apply it to "starting" date.

Comment: @Akina can you show me example to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hive or Spark-SQL:

```
select date_add (date_add(current_date,-15),s.i) as dt 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(15),' ')) as (i,x)) s
```

Result:

```
2020-05-18
2020-05-19
2020-05-20
2020-05-21
2020-05-22
2020-05-23
2020-05-24
2020-05-25
2020-05-26
2020-05-27
2020-05-28
2020-05-29
2020-05-30
2020-05-31
2020-06-01
2020-06-02
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56071699/2700344).

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT 1 num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL ... UNION ALL SELECT 15 )
SELECT DATEADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -num)
FROM cte;
```

Or, for example

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT 1 num UNION ALL 
          SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 5 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT 0 num 
          UNION ALL SELECT 1 
          UNION ALL SELECT 2 )
SELECT DATEADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -cte1.num - cte2.num * 5)
FROM cte1, cte2;
```