# How to use SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR in Hive Query?

Tags: sql, hive, calendar, hiveql

I am trying to use SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR in Hive. It works for Oracle SQL but how can we convert so that I can run following in Hive:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR` is a `Teradata` system view, not `Oracle`. There is no such table or view in `Hive`, but you can generate it or write a subquery in Hive which will return what you need.

See these questions:

[How can i generate a Date table with fields equals to "Dayofweek", "weekofyear" etc ;and rows equals to date from 2010-01-01 till current_date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55439561/2700344)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56071699/2700344

Alternatively you can load data from TD into Hive using Sqoop or export it into CSV then load into Hive table.

Comment: I think this:
FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )

Comment: @DineshMadhup if you need current date or timestamp then use `current_date` or `current_timestamp`, not `FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ) `